# Developing an add-in for Outlook on the Web for Sending Secure Email

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm working on a project that involves the development of an add-in for outlook the web for the purpose of sending secure email.

I have a few requirements for this add-in:

1. It must be able to have access to smart card reader and read certificates from it.
2. It must be able to sign and encrypt mail using S/MIME
3. Ideally, should also work on mobile (e.g. iPhone, Andriod).

From my current research, I understand that there are some restrictions regarding add-ins for Outlook. The main one being it won't be activated for encrypted mail... But I have noticed that some people are able to work around this limitation.

Hoping to get some promising leads from the experts here.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please describe your problem in more detail please, especially by adding code which you've tried to solve your issue even w/o success. The more specific your coding problem is, the better is the chance to get help from SO experts. Please have also a look to the help center regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. I'm still researching, and and can't find much information online. I was hoping someone here had some experience doing it. Is it a must to provide code for every question asked? Thanks.

Comment: Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently add-ins are not supported on S/MIME encrypted messages and are not available for mobile compose scenarios. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.